# Regex return values from a form result

Tags: c#, regex

The result of a web form is being sent to me via text mail and I need to parse all the values from it. I'd like to have a single regex which is capable of returning me a result for a given key.

```
String Pattern = String.Format("^.*{0}:\s*(?<mail><mailto\:)?(.*)(?(mail)>)\s*$", InputString);
```

I have these 2 options enabled: `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline`

#### Here's a portion of the text which needs to be parsed.

```
City:     Test City
Country:  Mycountry

Phone:    212
Fax:      
E-Mail:   <mailto:mymail@example.com>
```

This is working well except for the case in which there's no value, e.g. `Fax`. If I put `Fax` as InputString the complete next line `E-Mail:   <mailto:mymail@example.com>` is being returned. I want to have either no result or an empty one.

Comment: Why do you have `RegexOptions.Multiline`?

Comment: So the `^` and `$` match at the start and end of each line, not the whole input?

Comment: Because I want `^` and `$` to represent start and end of a line and not of the complete text mail.

Comment: It looks like `\s` is matching `\r` and `\n`, even though `.` doesn't match `\n` - not what I expected.

Comment: @Rawling If you are looking for newlines in `\.` use `[\S\s]` instead. Much more consistently implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that, even though you're not using `RegexOptions.SingleLine` and thus `.` doesn't match `\n`, the `\s` character class *does* match `\n`.

You can fix this by replacing every instance of `\s` with `[^\S\r\n]`, i.e. rather than matching "whitespace (including newlines)", match "not (a non-whitespace or newline)".

```
string pattern = String.Format(
    @"^[^\S\r\n]*{0}:[^\S\r\n]*(?<mail><mailto\:)?(.*)(?(mail)>)[^\S\r\n]*$",
    "Fax");
```

However, then you're left with another issue: `RegexOptions.Multiline` means `^` or `$` matches a `\n`, so you'll be left with a trailing `\r` on your match if the newlines in your match are `\r\n`.

To get around this, you can *not* use `RegexOptions.Multiline`, but instead replace `^` with `(?<=^|\r\n)` and `$` with `(?=$|\r\n)`, which manually matches a `\r\n` newline.

Comment: `[^\S\r\n]*` before the `$` wouldn't match the mailto pattern anymore. I don't know why but it works perfectly with `\s*$`. That way `Fax` still gives me an empty result back as I want. So this is what I am using now: `^[^\S\r\n]*{0}:[^\S\r\n]*(?<mail><mailto\:)?(.*)(?(mail)>)\s*$`

Comment: @Ben That's odd, I've jsut tried it with the email row and it seems to work :-/ Maybe we have different line endings or something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern and code which places the items into a dictionary for extraction. If the value is empty, its key is valid in the dictionary but the value contained or returned for that ke is null.

```
string data = @"City: Test City
Country: Mycountry
Phone: 212
Fax:
E-Mail: <mailto:mymail@example.com>";

string pattern = @"^(?<Key>[^:]+)(?::)(?<Value>.*)";

var resultDictionary =

Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .ToDictionary (mt => mt.Groups["Key"].Value, mt => mt.Groups["Value"].Value);

/* resultDictionary is a dictionary with these values:

City      Test City
Country   Mycountry
Phone     212
Fax
E-Mail  <mailto:mymail@example.com>
*/
```